# How can i add a Serviceaccout using kubectl patch to existing Clusterrolebinding

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

This is my existing clusterrolebinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: example-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: ns1
```

i am planning to add the same ServiceAccount (test-sa) in another namespace (for eg:ns2) and bind it with my ClusterRole "test-role" .

what i have tried

```
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: ns2
```

i tried to apply the yaml file above like

```
kubectl patch  clusterrolebinding <clusterrolebinding-name> --type="strategic"  --patch "$(cat role.yaml)"
```

Result

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: example-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: ns2
```

It is adding the  ClusterRoleBinding with sa in new namespace but my existing binding in namespace ns1 got removed .. is there any way to merge the new changes instead of replace ..iam trying do it in an automated way ..like a bash script for editing this cluserrolebinding,thats why i choose kubectl patch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below command. It worked. Refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#patching-resources).

```
kubectl patch clusterrolebinding example-role --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/subjects/1", "value": {"kind": "ServiceAccount", "name": "test-sa","namespace": "ns2" } }]'
```

`op` - operation `add`

`subjects/1` - add to subjects array's first position

```
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: ns1
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: ns2
```

Comment: According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902#section-4.1 "If the target location specifies an object member that does exist, that member's value is replaced.". More safety to use `subjects/-` to add to the end of an array.

Comment: @MaximSuslov - That quote doesn't apply here. We're adding to an array, not an object - so "If the target location specifies an array index, a new value is inserted into the array at the specified index." is the appropriate behaviour (and, indeed - I just tested and that's the behaviour demonstrated)